# Python sort lists with lists inside

Tags: python, list, sorting, python-2.7

Suppose a list of lists, something like this:

```
lists=[[3,2,1,4],[6,4,2,8],[9,6,3,12]]
```

If I want to sort by `lists[0]`it should be sorted like this:

```
lists=[[1,2,3,4],[2,4,6,8],[3,6,9,12]] #can be another variable
```

Having a list of three lists:

```
list1,list2,list3=(list(t) for t in zip(*sorted(zip(lists[0], lists[1],lists[2]))))
```

But that is a specific solution, n lists inside a list could be more general.
The `lists` variable was created like this:

```
lists = [[] for x in xrange(n)]
```

And the values were appended on.

Actually all values are numeric (float or int), but this might explain it better.

```
lists=[[3,2,1,4],["three","two","one","four"],["tres","dos","uno","cuatro"]]
```

I would like to know how to sort that and end up with this:

```
[[1,2,3,4],["one","two","three","four"],["uno","dos","tres","cuatro"]]
```

Comment: Use `*` notation on the list of lists: `zip(*lists)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be the unlikely case where it's best to use a Schwartzian transform

```
>>> lists=[[3,2,1,4],["three","two","one","four"],["tres","dos","uno","cuatro"]]
>>> [[x for i, x in sorted(zip(lists[0], sublist))] for sublist in lists]
[[1, 2, 3, 4], ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'], ['uno', 'dos', 'tres', 'cuatro']]
```